# unobtrusive javascript reloads data entry form before form is submitted

Tags: jquery, unobtrusive-javascript, unobtrusive-validation

I'm using ASP.Net MVC and implementing unobtrusive javascript for form validation.  Here's my code:

```
@{
   AjaxOptions options = new AjaxOptions
   { 
    HttpMethod = "Post",
    LoadingElementId = "ProcessingMessageContainer",
    Url = @Model.SaveUrl,
    OnBegin = "OnBegin",
    OnSuccess = "OnSaveSuccess",
    OnFailure = "OnSaveFailure",
    OnComplete = "OnComplete",
   };   
 }
 <div id="DataEntryFormContainer">
     @using (Ajax.BeginForm(options)) 
     {
        [form here]
     }
 </div>
```

The problem is when I press the submit button the form is reloaded before the actual submission is processed on the server.  So, it's a bad user experience.  The form data is delivered to the server and is processed accordingly.  How do you keep the data entry form from being reloaded after user presses the submit button?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  I somehow bound 2 different actions to submit button.  It was submitting the form and requesting the original page.  I caught it by watching the console using firebug.  Every time I submitted the form, i saw 2 requests to the server: 1 post for submitting the form and 1 get for retrieving the form.  Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have you haven't turned on Client Validation and Unobtrusive JavaScript in your Web.config file.

Double check that you have both of these lines in the Web.config:

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but those values are set in Web.config.  If I do not fill out a required form element, then validation works and catches it.  For some reason when I submit a totally valid form the form is reloaded and textbox values are cleared.

Comment: Ah okay. Are you returning anything from your save controller action? You could try setting an insertion mode to something other than replace and see if that helps?